# Rails: Uninstall specific version of a library using gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems

For example I have the following four versions installed:

> capybara (2.2.1, 2.2.0.rc1, 2.1.0, 1.1.4)

Please suggest how to uninstall the **capybara version 1.1.4**

Answer (score 96, accepted):

When you do `gem uninstall capybara` it should give you a menu asking which one you want to uninstall.

Alternatively use the `-v` option.

```
gem uninstall capybara -v 1.1.4
```

Note you may need to sudo these commands if you're not using rvm.

Answer (score 1):

You can also uninstall gems with version requirements using this format:

```
gem uninstall 'my_gem:1.0.0'
```

So you in your case, you would have:

```
gem uninstall 'capybara:1.1.4'
```

This also works when you want to uninstall multiple gems:

```
gem uninstall 'my_gem:1.0.0' 'my_other_gem:2.0.0'
```

**OR**

```
gem uninstall 'my_gem:1.0.0' 'my_other_gem:~>2.0.0'
```

So you in your case, you would have:

```
gem uninstall 'capybara:1.1.4' 'capybara:2.1.40'
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**